# Shop This Look / Shop By Look - Create page with multiple products and quickcart

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I’m wanting to build a Shop This Look page that will be easily editable and up-datable without too much hacking every time it’s updated.

Ideally I would like it to work like this: http://shop.crooksncastles.com/collections/shop-by-look-mens-look-2
In that I upload a photo of the look and then select the products to appear (Even if it’s through using their productids).

My thoughts on how to achieve this: 
1) Create a category specifically for each look but have them set to hidden. Eg.
 
Looks>
* Look1 
* Look2 
* Look3

2) Then display the category in a static block on a CMS page. And then add the selected products to the look categories.

The idea is that a customer can select their size and add each product of the look on that page without leaving.

Is this the correct way to go about this?

Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to greater utilise the category function of magento.

I built two new themes within my template file one for category and one for product list.

The category structure I used was

```
SHOP THIS LOOK > LOOK 1
               > LOOK 2
               > LOOK 3
```

The template that was applied to the 'Shop This Look' parent category had all product list snippets removed and only displayed the images of the sub categories (Look 1, Look 2 and Look 3).

I then added the look image to each of the Look 1 - Look 3 categories and the products (via the category products tab).

The Look pages also had their own list.phtml file. That displayed the category (look) image on the left hand side, then a list of the products down the right hand side. I edited it so the product images / titles didn't link through to the product any more and added a 'View full product details' link at the bottom. This encourages people to add their products to the page from the look and remain on the page to add the rest of the look.

Another good way to look into buying a whole look as opposed to selecting individual options is bundled products.

Over all functionality is exactly how I wanted it. Updating is easy for a Magento layman and it looks great.

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130553/implement-shop-the-look-feature)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to create your own module in app/local. 
Also you should take a look at configurable products and their attributes, maybe that's enough for what you want.

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130553/implement-shop-the-look-feature)

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative approach you can check Altima Lookbook to create "[Shop the look](http://shop.altima.net.au/altima-lookbook-professional.html)" experience.
It does it in a bit different way - allows you to place a slide (as part of slideshow) with multiple products linked with that slides as interactive tags, placed on top of actual image.